# Measure estimates of $\delta$-neighbourhood of compact sets

Tags: reference-request, mg.metric-geometry, geometric-measure-theory, geometric-probability

I am interested in the estimating from above the measure of a compact set $K$ by a sequence of sets $K_n$, converging to it in the Hausdorff metric. As such I am looking for known conditions that give such a control. As Hausdorff convegence translates to cover by $\delta$-fattening, one can study the measures of the  $K_n$ to hopefully deduce something about the measure of $K$.

I was told that facts about estimating measures of $\delta$-fattening was related to Geometric measure theory, but I really have no idea on this topic, and am not necessarily familiar with the terminiology relevant. Is there something known about estimating measures of $\delta$-fattenings of general sets, not necessarily being connected or convex? I would appreciate any reference, even when done in $\mathbb{R}$, since I have been unsucssesful so far.

The sort of estimates which I know but are not sufficient to me, are that if $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is a compact set with $q$ connected components, then

$$ \lambda(A^{(\delta)})\leq \lambda(A)+2q\cdot \delta $$
where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure. Does there exist a more refined estimate along these or similar lines?